# Need to understand piece of code in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagick, imagemagick-convert

I have the following piece of code from ImageMagick command line utility which I am trying to understand so that I can map it to Imagick php wrapper.

This is the command line code

```
convert $dir/tmpT.mpc -alpha off -colorspace gray -write $dir/tmpTG.mpc \
-crop ${wd}x${ht}+${minx}+${miny} +repage -format "%[fx:100*mean-50]" info:
```

First question is what the "info:" flag at the end does?

The second question is what the fx formula "%[fx:100*mean-50]" does?

The third question is, will the tmpTG.mpc stay intact when the -crop, +repage are applied to tmpT.mpc or not?

Please help me with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First question is what the "info:" flag at the end does?

The `info:` is a [coder protocol](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/coders/info.c), not a flag. The coder simply writes information to a buffer, in your case `STDOUT`. The information output was requested by the `-format` flag.

> The second question is what the fx formula "%[fx:100*mean-50]" does?

Two parts here. First is the [percent escape format](https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php), and it's requesting `info:` to output the evaluated output of an FX expression. Second, the [FX expression](https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php) `100*mean-50` is calculating the mean of all color values, and doing some basic arthritic. I assume it's attempting to identify how close to 50% light/darkness an image is.

> The third question is, will the tmpTG.mpc stay intact when the -crop, +repage are applied to tmpT.mpc or not?

The `-write $dir/tmpTG.mpc` is writing a cache file to disk *AFTER* removing alpha & grayscale operations, but *BEFORE* the crop & repage operations occur. It will not be affected, or updated.

Comment: thats awesome. BTW, I have a question, how can we calculate the "mean of all GRAY values" in the php version of ImageMagick (i.e. imagick) ?

Comment: Basically, what is the equivalent of "fx:100*mean-50" in Imagick?

Comment: That would be the [`Image.identifyFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.identifyformat.php) method.

Comment: identifyFormat method will return the fx: mean? Confusing

Comment: It accepts percent escape format, so you would pass `'%[fx:100*mean-50]'` as the `string $embedText ` argument.

Comment: Wow, genius. Thank you for all the support.

Comment: BTW, emcconville. What is xc: means in ImageMagick? What is the equivalent of it in Imagick. Also these parameters like xc: , info: are not well documented. Where can I refer these minor details?

Comment: `XC:` stands for x-canvas, and it has an alias of `CANVAS:`. Anthony’s Usage articles cover a lot of this, and so does the documentation that ships with the source code.

Comment: Could you direct me to Anthony's Usage articles please?  Also what x-canvas means?

Comment: Could you direct me to Anthony's Usage articles please?  Also what x-canvas means?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to post a link. [ImageMagick Usage](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/). No idea about the actual names behind things, but I would suspect it's related to [X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System). Also, remember that all of this is Open Source! There's nothing stopping you from opening the source code, and see how/why things work.

Comment: This is the logic I am trying to translate to php scale=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:($ww-1)/($topwidth-1)]" info:``\